# Logout using REST

Tags: ajax, 8

I am using Drupal 8.2.5 and Angular 1.6.1. I've found a few threads on this, but nothing seems to be working. I am using Angular to login and that is working fine: I get a response with my user info, CSRF token, logout token etc.

I've setup our server for CORS.

- Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://mylocalenv.dev"
- Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE"
- Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,X-CSRF-Token,Content-Type,Authorization"

  - Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

According to (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services) I simply call a get on `user/logout?_format=json`

What I am trying right now in angular is this:

```
logout: function() {
  $http.get('http://api.server.com/user/logout?_format=json',{
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': user.csrf_token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic encodedBasicAuthString'
    },
    withCredentials:true
});
```

which is resulting in a 403 forbidden and returning `{"message":""}`.

Any ideas? I can't find any information on what logout_token is for, but I'm sure it is relevant to this problem.

I am already setting `withCredentials` to `true`.

Comment: @WimMostrey I've combed through the thread. I even left some comments.

Comment: @kiamlaluno since you marked mine duplicate, how do you propose I find a solution?